# How to track Azure AD B2C errors using Correlation ID?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In Azure AD B2C, a user flow policy has been created with Twitter identity provider for sign in. On clicking the Twitter icon on sign in page for the application using the user flow policy, the following error is being shown:
[image]

I looked into the Azure portal's Audit logs but couldn't find the erroneous correlation Id listed there.
Is there any way I can find what's specifically causing that error so I can look for a solution in right direction?

Comment: Please check your TrustFrameworkBase.xml and TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml.

Comment: @ChauncyZhou It's the User Flow that is being used and not custom policies.

Comment: Have you followed all these steps thoroughly? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT The Twitter identity provider settings were made several years ago by a different set of developers. It has suddenly stopped working and is brought to our attention to fix it. I followed the steps mentioned in the link you provided in our test tenant and the integration was quick and seamless. Just want to get to the exact error so as to be able to address it without hit and trial method.

Answer (score 2):

**Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)** emits ***audit logs*** containing activity information about B2C resources, tokens issued, and administrator access. Audit log events are only retained for **seven days**.

***Note:*** You can't see user sign-ins for individual Azure AD B2C applications under the `Users` section of the Azure Active Directory or Azure AD B2C pages in the Azure portal. The sign-in events there show user activity, but **can't** be correlated back to the B2C application that the user signed in to. You must use the audit logs for that

This example image from the Azure portal shows the data captured when a user signs in with an external identity provider, in this case, Facebook:

[image]

***To view Audit logs:***

1. Sign in to Azure portal
2. Switch to the directory that contains your Azure AD B2C tenant, and then browse to `Azure AD B2C`.
3. Under Activities in the left menu, select `Audit logs`.

A list of activity events logged over the last seven days is displayed.

[image]

To download the list of activity events in a comma-separated values (CSV) file, select `Download`.

Comment: I already tried the above mentioned steps but could not find the correlation Id shown in Audit logs. I do not reach the Twitter sign in page even, the error is thrown before that. The Twitter account was set up several years before. 

I'm suspecting we may need to get new client id and secret from Twitter developer account but wanted to be sure that it's the root cause for this error.

Comment: Try setting up Twitter in B2C again and try testing the flow in incognito mode.

Comment: The following callback URL is set up in Twitter developer account: (https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp) Created new API key and secret and the same error is coming. We haven't yet migrated to b2clogin.com URLs. Please suggest next steps.

Comment: Pls perform all the steps mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter#create-an-application